# CodeIgniter - How to nest a view in view using second controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have this part in my View:

```
 <body>
    <div id = "content">
       <?php echo $catalog ?>
    </div>
 </body>
```

There are also other variables in it. Here is the part of my Controller where I send them to the View:

```
$this->load->view('layout',array(
        'categories'    =>  $categories,
        'home_menu'     =>  $home_menu,
        'information'   =>  $information,
        'favourite'     =>  $favourite,
        'new_products'  =>  $new_products,
        'bestsellers'   =>  $bestsellers,
        'login_info'    =>  $login_info,
        'catalog'       =>  ''
        ));
```

I want to create second controller, which when activated sends a second view to the variable `$catalog`.

Something like this (similar to Kohana):

```
$this->layout->catalog = $this->load->view('products/catalog', array(
                'name'          =>  $name,
                'description'   =>  $description));
```

But it's not working.

My question is, how can I show this second nested view after clicking on a link that activates the second Controller?

---

*EDIT:*

But I want to send the **catalog view** to **$catalog** variable after the user has clicked on a link that activates second controller, which look something like this:

```
 $products = $this->Product_model->list_products($category_id);
foreach ($products as $row)
        {
                     $name = $row->name;
                     $description = $row->description;
        }
```

.. after that I want **$name** and **$description** to be passed to:

```
$this->load->view('products/catalog', array(
                    'name'          =>  $name,
                    'description'   =>  $description));
```

..which itself to be passed to `$catalog` in the **layout** view defined in the first controller

Answer (score 3):

You can call a `$this->load->view` within the view's code but I would not recommend it.

Instead pass `true` as the 3rd parameter in the load view function and this will return the view rather than echo it straight out. Then you can assign that returned code to your original view.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to send the view using a second controller. I added details to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping I'm understanding your question fully, but if not, I apologize.

My guess is that you're loading the page with all of the 'extras' and want to be able to update the 'content' part of your page through a user initiated click.

If you're implementing a javascript based solution, then you just need a controller that will output the html fragment and inject that into the current page via an ajax call.

If you're not implementing javascript, then it would be an entire page refresh, so you would just rebuild the page and pass the selected catalog content to the controller.

**UPDATE**

To do this without ajax or hmvc, you need to get the contents from another controller into this controller, so you could just make an additional request with php:

```
$catalog_content = file_get_contents('/url_to_second_controller.html');
$this->load->view('layout',array(
    'categories'    =>  $categories,
    'home_menu'     =>  $home_menu,
    'information'   =>  $information,
    'favourite'     =>  $favourite,
    'new_products'  =>  $new_products,
    'bestsellers'   =>  $bestsellers,
    'login_info'    =>  $login_info,
    'catalog'       =>  $catalog_content
    ));
```

Comment: I want to make it without ajax, so the page refresh is not a problem.
So there is no way to make the code smaller (making the second controller give only value to **$content** )?
The only way is to  define all variables ( **$categories**, **$home_menu**, **$information**,etc.) including **$content** and load the **layout** view?

Comment: Well, of course there is, but it depends on your controller and structure. If you're using [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home), you can call those controllers from within controllers. If you'll be doing a lot of this, then I would recommend it. However, for just something this easy, I would just do a `file_get_contents()` call to the second controller and put that in the view.  See update in my answer.